# How to get image url from rss Feed

Tags: android, rss-reader

How to get Image from Rss feeds..
Here is my Rss feed url..

http://news.yahoo.com/rss/

Yahoo! News - Latest News & Headlines

http://news.yahoo.com/

http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/th/main_142c.gif

i want to get  from above  tag.

please help me..

Comment: Do you know about XML Parsing? Go with SAX Parsing.....

Comment: Check my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31744680/4845324